# How to extract and manipulate the data from an Excel sheet using Rust/Rhai language?

Tags: rust, rhai

I am new to the language Rhai. the scripting language of Rust, and I want to know how to use it to extract cells, rows, and columns from an Excel sheet.

I read the Rhai language documentation and still can't write except a few lines of code. I want to know how to programmatically think about solving the problem.

Comment: Try using one of the crates listed here: https://crates.io/search?q=excel, https://crates.io/search?q=xslx, https://crates.io/search?q=spreadsheet. You can try asking on Software Recommendations Stack Exchange: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: There are very few libraries available with Rhai bindings, so you'd likely have to create the interface between Rhai and a Rust excel library yourself in order to manipulate a sheet from a script. There is an extensive portion of the Rhai Book dedicated to [Rust Integration](https://rhai.rs/book/rust/index.html) for that.